# subspace topology on lower limit vs standard

Tags: general-topology

Let $(\mathbb{R},\tau)$ be the topological space of real numbers where $\tau$ is the standard topology on $\mathbb{R}$.

Let $(\mathbb{R},\tau_l)$ be the topological space of real numbers where $\tau_l$ is the lower limit topology. That is, elements of $\tau_l$ are subsets of $\mathbb{R}$ of the form $[a,b)$ where $a<b$ and $a,b \in \mathbb{R}$.

Given an example of a countably infinite subset of the reals say $A$, such that the subspace topology induced on $A$ when $\mathbb{R}$ has the standard is distinct than when the subspace topology induced on $A$ when $\mathbb{R}$ is endowed with $\tau_l$. So you get distinct open sets.

So my prime suspects when I hear countably infinite subset of $\mathbb{R}$ are typically $\mathbb{N}$, $\mathbb{Z}$, or $\mathbb{Q}$, but if I take $A=\mathbb{Q}$. Then $\mathbb{Q} \cap (a,b)$ is the same as $\mathbb{Q} \cap [a,b)$ whenever $a \in \mathbb{R} \backslash \mathbb{Q}$, right? Some help or possibly just a hint? Thanks in advance!

(of course, here I am taking the subspace topology to be the subspace intersect the open sets in the ambient or parent space)

Comment: The lower-limit topology on $\Bbb R$ is also called the Sorgenfrey Line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not true that all elements of $\tau_\ell$ are of the form $[a,b)$: those half-open intervals simply form a base for $\tau_\ell$.

$\Bbb Q$ will work: $0$ is the limit of the sequence $\left\langle-\frac1n:n\in\Bbb Z^+\right\rangle$ in the topology inherited from $\tau$, but not in the topology inherited from $\tau_\ell$, since $[0,1)\cap\Bbb Q$ is a $\tau_\ell$-open nbhd of $0$ that contains no term of the sequence.

In fact, you could simply use the subspace $\{0\}\cup\left\{-\frac1n:n\in\Bbb Z^+\right\}$.